# What is a simple algorithm for 2d collision detection of transformable rectangular objects?

Tags: collision-detection

I implement a rectangular collision detection, but I then notice a flaw that it cannot take a transforming detection. Suppose I have two rectangle that collide face to face on a horizontal plane and stop, the two rectangle will be right next to each other. However, if one rectangle resizes and has its width expand, and if I use the center as reference point, then it will overlap other rectangle. I used a linkedlist to browse pointer to colliding rectangle, and these pointers can return different colliding rectangle depending on the state of the object (For e.g. if player is standing, then it is return size of standing, if he's crouching, it return size of crouching and so on).

I want to retain the list-browsing-pointer design, but then there should be a rect changes checking each time pointer is lookup. Therefore, is there a way to retain the design while implement transformable collision detection? or if there is a much simpler way, please educate me.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just test each edge from one rectangle for intersection against each edge in the other? Doesn't get much more simple than that. You could additionally do two point-in-polygon tests to determine whether one rectangle is completely enclosed by the other.